# Can I use << EOF but let user complete the input

Tags: bash, here-document

The need for this arose from the script below. It connects to a remote PC using anyconnect's vpn utility. First it asks for the one-time-password, connects, starts an RDP client and disconnects after the RPD client app has been closed.

```
if [ $# == 1 ]; then
    ONE_TIME_PWD=$1;
else
    printf "Enter the one-time password: ";
    read ONE_TIME_PWD;
fi

vpn -s connect <domain> << EOF
<user>
<pin>$ONE_TIME_PWD
EOF

# Use some RDP client here like xfreerdp or rdesktop

vpn -s disconnect <domain>
```

The problem is that one-time-password may change during the execution of `vpn -s connect <domain>`. So I was curious whether it's possible to change the script so that it lets me enter the one-time-password after `<pin>` has been inserted automatically? I've tried it with `head -c -1` to remove the last newline char but the input was still finished. Any other solution not based on EOF is acceptable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always do:

```
{
  printf '<user>\n<pin>'
  printf 'Enter the one-time password: ' > /dev/tty
  IFS= read -r otp < /dev/tty
  printf '%s\n' "$otp"
} | vpn -s connect <domain>
```

Which prompts for the password after `vpn` has been started and already fed `<user>\n<pin>`.

It reads the password and prints the prompts on the tty device, alternatively you could read from stdin (remove the `< /dev/tty`) and print the prompt on stderr (replace `> /dev/tty` with `>&2`).

If using `zsh` instead of `bash`, you could simplify that to:

```
{
  printf '<user>\n<pin>'
  IFS= read -rse '?Enter the one-time password: '
} | vpn -s connect <domain>
```

- `-s` to suppress the terminal `echo` (that one also supported by `bash`), preferable to input passwords.
- `-e` to echo the entered text on stdout instead of storing into a variable
- `?prompt`, prompt string sent on stderr, same syntax as `ksh`. `bash` has a `-p` option for that.

Comment: Something goes wrong here. The output starts with
Enter the one-time password: Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client (version 4.6.02074) .

Copyright (c) 2004 - 2018 Cisco Systems, Inc.  All Rights Reserved.
...

As you can see I have no chance to enter something

Comment: @ka3ak well yes. both parts of the pipeline are run together so you can enter the password after vpn has started as you asked. You can add a `sleep 1` before the prompt if you want it to be printed after vpn's initialisation message.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do something similar to this -

```
$: head -1 <<!
hello, $(head -1<$(tty))!
!
```

But I don't recommend it for several reasons.

Only slightly better -

```
$: head -1 <<!
 hello, $(read -rs pw <$(tty); echo "$pw" )!
!

 hello, world!
```

Still, it's what you asked.